# RFC for remote call transaction

Tags: abap, saprfc, jco

How do I call the SAP report (for example RSPARAM) with help JCo?

What RFC may be used to remotely call SA38 transaction with RSPARAM (e.t.c.) as parameter and then return results for later work ?

Answer (score 3):

RFC is for calling function modules, not programs. It's possible to use some generic function module to start a report, but since you'll usually want to process the results of the program and the program does not know that it was meant to deliver its results in a machine-readable way, you probably won't get too far this was. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want remote call "report RSPARAM" and process results in my script.

Answer (score 3):

With the nearly infinite possible results of calling a transaction, i don't think there is a RFC to execute such an operation and return a result. What would be the result in case of an ALV display, or if the program then wait for some interactions ?

You can display a transaction in SAP portal using transactions Iviews. You're then using the portal page as a HTMLGui for your transaction.

also, some FM can sometime be used to perform operations instead of a full program (ie HR_INFOTYPE_OPERATION instead of pa30).

regards
Guillaume

**Edition** : since you want the result of RRSPARAM, you could encapsulate the "important" part (form SHOW_ACTUAL_PAR_VALUES_ALV) in a module function accessible by RFC, and returning a table of CST_RSPFPAR_ALV (ie the same structure that is displayed in the report)

regards

Answer (score 0):

If You don't find a function to call, just create one by yourself. Tag it as callable from outside via RFC and in the coding, perform such things as "submit report xyz with param1 = value1 ... and return ... exporting list to memory". Then you can even return list output from this. Define the interface of the freshly created function module as you need (that means, report name as input, list output as a table of strings, e.g.). Attention, there is of course a big security risk, having an remote function accepting variable reportnames. But I am sure You know :-)